# i need my player in unity to teleport to a certain location when he touches a tagged object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need my player to teleport somewhere when he bumps into a (unity) gameobject with a certain tag (`are you seen`) on it. I already found a solution, but then I switched my player's movement to a character controller and now it doesn't work. This is my current script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class found: MonoBehaviour
{
      private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
      {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "are you seen")
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(-15.38f, 1.93f, 62.1f);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you switched to character controller, did you remove the `rigidbody` and `collider`? An [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) event still requires the player to have a collider with `IsTrigger = true`, and one of the gameobjects to have a rigidbody. Here is what the offical documentation says.

> Note: Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.

Comment: thank you, I knew that it needed a `rigidbody` and `istrigger` enabled, I just wanted to know if there was a different way that didn't require `rigidbody`  do you know of an alternative ?

Comment: You can check `IsKinematic` to true to remove any physics from the rigidbody while preserving the `trigger` methods.